# How to make a dot density Venn diagram in R?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, venn-diagram

I have a proteomic dataset with proteins all of which are in set A and some of which fall in sets B, C, and D. Using the r package [eulerr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eulerr/index.html), I was able to construct a Venn diagram of to visualize the intersection of these sets. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mndq5.png)

However, it occurred to me that the "filters" used to generate sets B, C, and D may be preferentially filtering out low intensity proteins. To visualize this, I thought to construct a [dot density Venn diagram](https://dvatvani.github.io/static/Venn-diagrams/Venn.png), in which each dot represents a protein colored by its intensity. Is such a plot possible in R? I found a [blog post](https://dvatvani.github.io/dot-density-venn-diagrams.html#dot-density-venn-diagrams) detailing a similar technique in Python, but I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with the language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[complex-upset](https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset/) offers utilities to create dot density diagrams in R (following the ggplot2 approach, see [documentation](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html#venn-diagrams)).

[image: venn diagram with dots]

Let's load and filter some data for an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ComplexUpset)
movies = as.data.frame(ggplot2movies::movies)
genres = c('Comedy', 'Drama', 'Action')
movies[genres] = movies[genres] == 1
movies[movies$mpaa == '', 'mpaa'] = NA
movies = na.omit(movies)
```

First, you need to arrange the data

```
movies_subset = head(movies, 300)

movies_subset$good_rating = movies_subset$rating > mean(movies_subset$rating)
arranged = arrange_venn(movies_subset, sets=genres)
```

Then, you can plot it with standard ggplot2 functions and new geoms provided by complex-upset: `geom_venn_region`, `geom_venn_circle`, `geom_venn_label_set`:

```
(
    ggplot(arranged)
    + theme_void()
    + coord_fixed()
    + geom_venn_region(movies_subset, sets=genres_subset, alpha=0.2)
    + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=region), size=1.5)
    + geom_venn_circle(movies_subset, sets=genres_subset, size=2)
    + geom_venn_label_set(movies_subset, sets=genres_subset, aes(label=region), outwards_adjust=2.6)
    + scale_color_venn_mix(movies, sets=genres_subset, guide='none')
    + scale_fill_venn_mix(
          movies, sets=genres_subset,
          guide='none',
          highlight=c('Comedy-Action', 'Drama'),
          inactive_color='white'
      )
)
```

It can also annotate individual points (and more!)

[image]

But this implementation has a few limitations:

- it only supports up to three sets
- it is slow to arrange with large datasets (>1000 observations)
- often fine-tuning the arrangement parameters is required to get a desired result
- as of the day of writing there are some minor improvements available in latest version which can be installed from GitHub but not from CRAN (yet)

Disclaimer: I am the author of ComplexUpset.